# How to add a linux environment variable for different language (PHP or RUBY)

Tags: php, ruby, environment-variables, development-environment, production

I would like to add a linux environment variable for my differents applications written in PHP and Ruby.

Its goal is to differntiate between 'production' and 'development' linux environment.

**How to have an linux environment variable (ex : APPLICATION_ENV='production') that can be accessed with PHP and Ruby?**

thanks

*Edit 1 :*

My first solution was :

for Apache/PHP in vhost :

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV 'production'
```

for Ruby :

```bsh
export APPLICATION_ENV='production'
```

```rb
puts ENV['APPLICATION_ENV']
```

**However, this is two places to the same value... There are no solution to merge it in one place ?** *par exemple to use /etc/environment*

Edit :

The answer of my question is detailed here : [Inserting Variable Headers in Apache](http://php.dzone.com/news/inserting-variable-headers-apa&default=false&zid=159&browser=16&mid=0&refresh=0)

Comment: Is the code run from the command line or from a web server (and if web server, which)?

Comment: The php code run from command line and from a apache serveur and ruby code run from command line

Comment: What distribution are you using ?

Comment: My distribution : Centos 6.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution to have a central location for your variable would be to put it in `/etc/environment` and include it in `/etc/init.d/httpd`.

```
$ vim /etc/environment
APPLICATION_ENV=production

$ vim /etc/init.d/httpd
if [ -f /etc/environment ]; then
  . /etc/environment
fi
```

Then restart apache with `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` and it should be OK.

If you are using ubuntu 16.04 or similar, replace `/etc/init.d/httpd` with `/etc/init.d/apache2`

If you don't want to include environment file to apache, you can directly put your code in `/etc/apache2/envvars` for example at the end of the file:
`export HELLO='dear'`

Comment: yes it's good ! However, what is the perfect solution without to edit /etc/init.d/httpd ?

Comment: There is no better solution AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Here is a detailed answer http://php.dzone.com/news/inserting-variable-headers-apa&default=false&zid=159&browser=16&mid=0&refresh=0

Answer (score 1):

For the commandline, do a

```
export APPLICATION_ENV='production'
```

prior to calling your code, like Domon suggested. You can write a short wrapper bash script to do all of that in one line, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
export APPLICATION_ENV='production'
ruby /path/to/your/script.rb
```

For apache, make sure mod_env is loaded, and include the line

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
```

in the site's vhost config or .htaccess.

Finally, you can set the APPLICATION_ENV globally on your system (using whatever your distri supports for that) and then simply pass the value to your web app by using

```
PassEnv APPLICATION_ENV
```

Comment: yes it's good. However, this is two places to the same value. I have edit my question.

Comment: Yes but i must to add the same value export and and SetEnv. This is not ideal I think

Comment: No, you do not. PassEnv will pass whatever is in APPLICATION_ENV to your web application. You just have to set the value once.

Comment: In fact, Apache do not use created variable with export APPLICATION_ENV='production' ?

Comment: It has to be set when Apache starts, if you simply set it on the shell, Apache will not see it

Comment: In centos, i "export APPLICATION_ENV='production'" in /etc/environment AND "PassEnv APPLICATION_ENV" in my vhost.conf. However, i have this message when restart apache => PassEnv variable APPLICATION_ENV was undefined.

Comment: Have you restarted the machine after modifying /etc/environment? If yes, please head on over to Superuser for specific system administration questions.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is specifying environment variables directly in shell commands. Then you can access them through the `ENV` object in Ruby.

For example, create a file called `env.rb`:

```rb
puts ENV['APPLICATION_ENV']
```

And run it in the shell like this:

```
APPLICATION_ENV='production' ruby env.rb
```

It should print out the word "production".

Or, use the `export` command:

```
export APPLICATION_ENV='production'
ruby env.rb
```

You might want to add the `export` line to some config file. For example, if you use bash, add it to `~/.bashrc` and it will get executed every time when you starts a new shell.

Comment: thanks, however this technical does not allow to access the variable in php in apache ?

Comment: @BastienD: In PHP, you can get the environment variable like this: `$_ENV['APPLICATION_ENV']`

Comment: if i run export APPLICATION_ENV='production' I have nothing in $_ENV when run my php script with Apache

Comment: @BastienD: You have to set it in the right config file. For example, export it in `/etc/apache2/envvars`. Then add `PassEnv APPLICATION_ENV` to the correct file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*`.

Comment: However, this is two places to the same value... There are no solution to merge it in one place ?